# Django can't import class in subdir of app when deployed with apache&mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Django (1.5.12) and httpd-2.2.15-29 in centos6.5 with python 2.6.6.

Really wierd error, and I am stuck. Please help me!

My project tree looks like:

```
/opt/django-demo
|-- api
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- **views.py**
|   |-- utils
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- **debug.py**
|-- demo
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
```

I need to import **utils.debug** in **views.py**:

```
from api.utils import debug
```

It works in django runserver, but not apache:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxxxx/xxxx/
Django Version: 1.5.12
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: No module named utils
Exception Location: /opt/django-demo/api/debug.py in <module>, line 9
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/opt/django-demo',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/webkit-1.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
 '/opt/django-demo/api/utils']
```

From the errors you can see, the subdir already added in PYTHONPATH by wsgi.py.
And no missing `__init__.py`.

After I mv utils/debug.py to api/debug.py:

```
from api import debug
```

It works!!!

So, why?

Comment: Since `/opt/django-demo/api/utils` is in the python path you can just: `import debug`.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, that works! But why? I need to add several subdirs, need I add them all in PYTHONPATH? '/opt/django-demo' already in PYTHONPATH, why not `from api.utils import debug` work?

Comment: Basically you see the PYTHONPATH in the output. You can import something is that exists in any of this pathes. In your case you have `/opt/django-demo/api/utils` in the PYTHONPATH, so the import will just find the `debug.py` there. You should also be able to import `from api.utils import debug` that would match to the first path. Most important for development are two things: a) don't have name collisions, if there are two packages/modules with the same name things can get nasty and b) make sure the PYTHONPATH settings do no differ when you run you code differently.

Answer (score 0):

Finally get the problem solved.
It seems there are bugs in debug.py, which need to be imported.
After fixing the bug, this error disapears.

Even '/opt/django-demo/api/utils' needn't be added in PYTHONPATH.